# How would I update the title of a YouTube livebroadcast via a Bash script?

Tags: bash, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have a YouTube channel that has a number of live broadcasts throughout the week, I am just looking for a way for the Title and Description to be updated via a crontab.

I have see seen the following link. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/update

To be honest I cant make any sense of it.

Any help offered greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You're in front of a non-trivial API, but that should not discourage you to go ahead with it.

I'd recommend Python as implementation language: go use the Google's [APIs Client Library for Python](https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client).

Basically, this library is of good quality and (compared to other client libraries) simple to use. It will, for example, insulate you from having to deal explicitly with REST API calls, JSON and the like. Your code will also work under both GNU/Linux and Windows.

You may begin your journey by reading the official getting started docs: [Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/python) and [YouTube Live Streaming API Overview](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/getting-started). Then I recommend absorbing these two important documents: [Life of a Broadcast](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/life-of-a-broadcast) and [Understanding Broadcasts and Streams](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/broadcasts-and-streams).

Then go read, understand and run the following sample program from Google: [`create_broadcast.py`](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/python/create_broadcast.py). Of course, you'll have to adapt that code to your use case.

You'll have to exercise patience and perseverance (since I imply that you have no prior experience using the YouTube Data API). Using this API will pay off to you at the end of your (programming) journey.

A special mention: for to be able to call the live streaming APIs you will first need to get acquainted with the things related to the so-called OAuth 2.0 authorization and authentication: [Implementing OAuth 2.0 Authentication](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/authentication). There's an official document that you need absorb: [OAuth 2.0 for Mobile & Desktop Apps](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/installed-apps).

A few more references: the live streaming API has an [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/) too. The main site documenting the client library is: [Google API Client Library for Python Docs](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/). Its source is public, to be found within the [client library's public repo](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/) under the directory [`docs`](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/master/docs).

Also useful is to see the [YouTube Data API's list of all instance methods](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/youtube_v3.html).